# SQL Query Getting Lag Time

Tags: sql

I have a table that has two fields in it called RunId and LastUpdated.  I am trying to put together a query that can take the LastUpdated date time and get the time difference from the previous RunId but there may be a gap.  Example:

```
RunId  LastUpdated
110    2020-05-11 05:06:27.000
113    2020-05-11 05:06:31.000
```

Is there a way to get the RunId and time diff such as this:

```
RunId     TimeDiff
113       0:00:04
```

Thanks for any info

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the last updated value for the previous run id using `lag()`:

```
select t.*, lag(lastupdate) over (order by runid) as prev_lastupdated
from t;
```

Then you can use your database-specific date/time functions to get the difference.  It might be as simple as `-` or it might require a special function.